# How to get the Color Profile data for an image on disk in swift

Tags: swift, file, cocoa, nsimage

Can't quite get how to programmatically get everything in the More Info section for any given photo in swift. I specifically am interested in Color profile data. Any ideas?

[image: Ordinary file information]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out to be quite easy:

```
let path = // Some Image path on disk
let url = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: path)
let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(url as CFURL, nil)
if imageSource != nil {
let imageProperties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imageSource!, 0, nil)
var dict = imageProperties as! Dictionary<String, Any>
print(dict["ProfileName"]!)
}
```